# Train/Test Set Proportion in cv.glmnet from glmnet package in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I was just wondering what is the percentage of train and test set in cv.glmnet from glmnet package in R. I have already read the glmnet package documentation and no information was included regarding the train/test set proportion. Please tell me if I missed something from the package documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the help page for `?cv.glmnet` there are two parts to look at:

Argument `nfolds`

> number of folds - default is 10. Although nfolds can be as large as
> the sample size (leave-one-out CV), it is not recommended for large
> datasets. Smallest value allowable is nfolds=3

And from the **Values** section for `foldid`

> if keep=TRUE, the fold assignments used

ie. set `keep=TRUE` in the function argument to access the folds afterwards

The function will put each row in to 10 roughly equally sized groups/folds. Then it will run 10 iterations of the model, leaving one of these out each time for testing. So its 90% train and 10% test but repeated 10 times.

You can supply your own folds with the `foldid` argument if you prefer. Hope that helps :)